# MVC Problem Populating JQuery DataTable From JSon Object on Button Click

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a MVC page with a JQuery DataTable that I want to populate when the user clicks the Query Button.

Here is my DataTable:

```
<table id="mytable" class="table table-striped table-bordered mt-5">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
        <th>Column 4</th>
        <th>Column 5</th>
        <th>Column 6</th>
        <th>Column 7</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Here is where I initialize the table (table is empty when page loads and not to be populated until user clicks the Query button):

```
$('#mytable').DataTable({
    processing: true, // for show progress bar
    order: [[2, "desc"]],
    dataSrc: 'vm',
    dom: 'rfltip',
    bRetrieve: true,
    iDisplayLength: 50,
    columns: [
        { "data": "COL1" },
        { "data": "COL2" },
        { "data": "COL3" },
        { "data": "COL4" },
        { "data": "COL5" },
        { "data": "COL6" },
        { "data": "COL7" }
    ]
});
```

And here is the function that gets called when the user clicks the Query button:

```
function QueryEvents() {
      $.ajax({
            url: "/MyController/MyJsonRequest",
            type: "get",
            data: {
                id: $("#id").val()
            },
            error: function (response) {

                console.log("response: " + response);
            }

        })
        .done(function (result) {              

            var table = $('#mytable').DataTable();
            table.clear().draw();
            console.log('good to here' + JSON.stringify(result));
            table.rows.add(result).draw();

        });
};
```

The call to the controller is working find and is returning a Json object. Here is the object listing from the console.log entry, so I know data is being returned:

```
good to here{"vm":[{"COL1":"0000000017","COL2":"Balance - 4 Place","COL3":"2334234","COL4":"INS1234","COL5":"smith, joe","COL6":"Yearly Maint","COL7":"/Date(1582314988910)/"},{"COL1":"0000000018","COL2":"Balance - 4 Place","COL3":"2334234","COL4":"INS1234","COL5":"jones, billy","COL6":"Yearly Maint","COL7":"/Date(1582314988910)/"}]}
```

It is well formed json and I am not getting any errors, but the dataTable is not populated. Not sure what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is your object which you printed on console.

```
{"vm":[{"COL1":"0000000017","COL2":"Balance - 4 Place","COL3":"2334234","COL4":"INS1234","COL5":"smith, joe","COL6":"Yearly Maint","COL7":"/Date(1582314988910)/"},{"COL1":"0000000018","COL2":"Balance - 4 Place","COL3":"2334234","COL4":"INS1234","COL5":"jones, billy","COL6":"Yearly Maint","COL7":"/Date(1582314988910)/"}]}
```

But DataTable only requires inner array.

```
[{"COL1":"0000000017","COL2":"Balance - 4 Place","COL3":"2334234","COL4":"INS1234","COL5":"smith, joe","COL6":"Yearly Maint","COL7":"/Date(1582314988910)/"},{"COL1":"0000000018","COL2":"Balance - 4 Place","COL3":"2334234","COL4":"INS1234","COL5":"jones, billy","COL6":"Yearly Maint","COL7":"/Date(1582314988910)/"}]
```

So you should use

```
table.rows.add(result.vm).draw();
```

instead of

```
table.rows.add(result).draw();
```